# Display only integer values in yAxis in ColumnChart

Tags: jquery

I'm developing Google chart in that i have taken `ColumnChart`, here `yAxis` in chart showing decimal values instead of that i want to display only integer values, below in my creating `datatable` code,

```
var datatable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['', '', { role: 'style' }, { role: 'annotation'}],
    ['Billable Time', parseFloat(gettimevalue(data.BillableTime)), 'color: #ADCEE7', data.BillableTime],
    ['Effort Time', parseFloat(effortTime), 'color: #F0CA54',effortTime],
    ['Punch Time', parseFloat(punchTime), 'color: #A8C74A',punchTime]
  ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can  use like this if you  want show the integer value on Y a

vAxis: {
    format: '#'
}

Comment: Hi ASH, its working thank you so much for your reply, now yaxis showing 5,8,10,13,15 instead of this i want like 5,10,15..how to do this...please help me.

Comment: Babu Reddy can you tell me which type of chart you are using like bar chart ,line chart etc

Answer (score 0):

instead of that we can devide our y axis numbers for example highest value in my y axis is 16 then if we devide it to 4 then y axis will contain 4,8,12,16...
below is the code to devide the y axis

```
     vAxis: {
```

gridlines: { count: 4 }
}

or u can refere this link
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.Range you can give according to you.

vAxis: {
    viewWindow: {
        min: 0,
        max: 20
    },
    ticks: [0, 4,8, 12, 16,20] 
}